# How to getCount multi private int

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i'm new android java programming. i'm using `ListView` multiple image. but i have a issue about **`public int getCount()`**. i want to know how to do multiple int image not error. i try to find information. can't find the information i want to know

```
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class Main2Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context context;
            private int[] intspic;
            private int[] rawspic;
            private String[] StringsName;
            private String[] StringsDetail;

            public Main2Adapter(Context context,
                               int[] intspic,
                               int[] rawspic,
                               String[] stringsName,
                               String[] stringsDetail) {
                this.context = context;
                this.intspic = intspic;
                this.rawspic = rawspic;
                StringsName = stringsName;
                StringsDetail = stringsDetail;
            }

            @Override
            public int i getCount() {
                return rawspic,intspic.length;
            }


            @Override
            public Object getItem(int i) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int i) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout_ii, viewGroup, false);
                ImageView imageViews = (ImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.imageViewii);
                ImageView rawii = (ImageView) view2.findViewById(R.id.imageRawii);
                TextView Names = view2.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
                TextView Details = view2.findViewById(R.id.textView22);

                rawii.setImageResource(rawspic[i]);
                imageViews.setImageResource(intspic[i]);
                Names.setText(StringsName[i]);
                Details.setText(StringsDetail[i]);
                return view2;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess all of these arrays have the same length:

```
private int[] intspic;
private int[] rawspic;
private String[] StringsName;
private String[] StringsDetail;
```

so `getCount()` may return the length of one of them:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rawspic.length;
}
```

Edit rereturn intspic.length; to rereturn intspic.length;

Comment: sorry compile complete but open app alert "app keeps stopping" i think private int not working not loop image

Comment: This means that the app crashes. In Android Studio click Logcat and check the error message.

Comment: i think private not all work. if delete one int app no problem and work all photo

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying. As for your code, copy and paste the method `getCount()` as it is in my answer.

Comment: OK, i find guidelines and "app" work i'm edit answer you please see code

Comment: If all the arrays have the same length then you can choose any of the arrays in `getCount()`. It's fine.